# "(subgroups)" tag, not "(sub-groups)"

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

I am noticing that the [sub-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sub-groups) tag [is created](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sub-groups). But it should be spelled [subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subgroups), without a hyphen. I attempted to modify and create a tag with the correct spelling; however I received this notice:

[image: You are attempting to create the tag [subgroups]...]

Should this tag be changed accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

I have merged [sub-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sub-groups) into [subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subgroups) (which effectively just renamed the tag).

I am not personally convinced of the viability of even the correctly spelled tag. That's probably a topic for the other thread.

Comment: [Some context](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21930593#21930593) (I removed this tag, too).